# TensorFlow Object Detection API with Imagenet classes?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

In TensorFlow's Object Detection API:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection

Is it possible to classify using the ImageNet classes (1000 classes)?  The 4-5 models in the Model Zoo are all trained on the COCO dataset, which only has 80 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can convert imagenet data to torecord, and train imagenet detection model, it is the same with coco or pascal_voc procedure.
Here I write a script  [tensorflow_object_detection_create_coco_tfrecord](https://github.com/MetaPeak/tensorflow_object_detection_create_coco_tfrecord) to convert coco data to tfrecord for tensorflow object detection API, you can refer to this to convert your own data